# Control the size of a string field with mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

i am trying to find documentation about how to control or limit the size of a field in mongodb.

I have a schema whitch has a field that is type string and i would like to limit the size.

Sometimes the users are inserting big descriptions and i would like to control the size.

Is there any method when i declare the schema to set a max size or something? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//actual code out from mongo 4.2 shell/"command line interface" on windows
//create a collection emp and name as one of the fields. Use schema validation to limit //name size during schema creation
> db.createCollection("emp",{
...     validator:{
...         $jsonSchema:{
...             bsonType:"object",
...             properties:{
...              name:{
...                 bsonType: "string",
...                 description: "must be string",
...                 maxLength: 10
...             }
...         }
...       }
...     }
... }
... );
{ "ok" : 1 }
//insert sample document for name greater than lenght say 10 characters.
//it fails
> db.emp.insert({name:"kasjdfdj abcdeefghijddfldkjslfj"});
WriteResult({
        "nInserted" : 0,
        "writeError" : {
                "code" : 121,
                "errmsg" : "Document failed validation"
        }
})
//insert document for name less than 10, it passes through
> db.emp.insert({name:"john doe"});
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
//table level validation
> db.emp.find();
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f5fa20fbc3501568e2ee9f0"), "name" : "john doe" }
>
```

Comment: It seems that works but do you know how to do this validation with the mongoose schema?

Comment: @sergioCano, sorry. I don't have knowledge of mongoose. I think its a some kind of query modeller on top of MongoDB.

Comment: thank you for you answer, in mongoose is kind of similar, there are some validators i think this answer is enough to understand how validators works.

Answer (score 1):

Mongoose has several built-in validators. For String, it has *enum*, *match*, *minlength*, and *maxlength* validators. Look like *maxlength* is what you need.

You can read more about mongoose built-in validators [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#built-in-validators).